# SQL queries to get the duplicate records based on trim

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, query, group-by, trim

I have a table that has got the below set of records.

```
UNMASK  MASK
123 897609
00123   896509
0000456 5632789
456 32567889
5678    5632789
```

From the above table I need to select only the below records.

```
  UNMASK    
123 
00123   
0000456 
456
```

(I.E) Whatever values in UNMASK has any number of '0' before the '1-9' and also the row that doesn't have 0s before that 1-9.

Like 123 and there can be 000000123, 456 and 00456, I need such records(only Prefixed with 0s and the original value) in the output using SQL query in Oracle.

I tried the below query but it doesn't work the way I want.

```
Select UNMASK,TRIM (LEADING '0' FROM UNMASK) from HSA.TEST_TABLE group by UNMASK having count(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM UNMASK)) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test data:

```
create table test_table(unmask varchar(20), mask varchar(20));
insert into test_table values('123', '897609');
insert into test_table values('00123','896509');
insert into test_table values('0000456','5632789');
insert into test_table values('456','32567889');
insert into test_table values('5678','5632789');
```

I've done this with a CTE, as I love them. `cast`ing the string to a `number` removes the leading characters, which I find easier than messing around with `TRIM`.

Query:

```
with duplicates as 
(
  select cast(unmask as number) as unmask_num, count(*) as cnt
  from test_table
  group by cast(unmask as number)
  having count(*)>1
)
select *
from duplicates
join test_table on duplicates.unmask_num = cast(unmask as number)
;
```

DB Fiddle that demonstrates is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e5c870f7c89159b0759a4cd54513e862).

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it in 2 steps, first find "duplicates":

```
Select TRIM (LEADING '0' FROM UNMASK) 
from HSA.TEST_TABLE 
group by TRIM (LEADING '0' FROM UNMASK)  
having count(1) > 1;
```

From there you can join with the original table:

```
select tt.*
from HSA.TEST_TABLE tt
join (
    Select TRIM (LEADING '0' FROM UNMASK) as unmask 
    from HSA.TEST_TABLE 
    group by TRIM (LEADING '0' FROM UNMASK)  
    having count(1) > 1
) t
    on t.unmask = TRIM (LEADING '0' FROM tt.UNMASK)
```

All untested since neither table ddl nor insert statements for sample data where availible

Comment: HI,It works. But what if the datatype of UNMASK column is VARCHAR2 and it also has alphabets. The above command wont work right?

Comment: It just removes leading '0' from the string, so I assume it should work.